Signing in AWS Identity Center from Entra
I finished configuring SCIM synchronization between Microsoft Entra and Amazon IAM Identity center, where my users, as well as, groups can be provisioned to IAM Identity Center. However, when I tried to test a user sign on through Entra to AWS i get an error.
The error says "It's not you, it's us"
I went through all the steps again and i made sure the certificates and everything was added properly. I'm not too sure how to get past this error.
There is a request ID of: 431e7693-e896-4105-b679-0da699e1ba0c, but nothing shows when i google it.
Any thoughts?

Have you checked that you’ve assigned the Permission Set on the AWS side for the synced user/group? Last time I got that error, I forgot to add the permission set assignment.

Thank you for your response, i have an assigned permission set to the group. The problem seems to be with the accounts provisioned with SCIM, because when i manually provison an account via SAML, they can log in to the dashboard fine.
